Timetravel/Dimension travel with necklace/medallion
My mom has mentioned many times about a preview she saw years ago...I'm guessing around 2000, but I am uncertain.
The only details she can give me is in the preview, there is a male as the main character and he has a female companion (for at least part of the movie). He carries with him a necklace or medallion that allows him to jump between either dimensions or to relocate in an entirely new area. The necklace/medallion is spun to change the setting of the characters.
I guess in a clip in the preview, the man and woman are on top of a building and have to jump off for some reason and the man is reluctant to jump, but the woman says, "you have to do it. Do it now!"...or at least something to that affect. Do you have any idea what she maybe talking about?
I am unable to suggest the proper movie. I think she is looking for something like the show Sliders, but she says it's a movie.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleportation_in_fiction#Films ?

It doesn't happen to be that, or that, or that, does it?

Harry Potter, Prisoner of Azkaban?

The movie you're thinking of is Crossworlds with Rutger Hauer from 1996.



